# Angular 2 *ngFor re renders elements

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have this ngFor reading data from a Firebase database:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of myPosts | async" >
```

Each time a new post is being pushed, all of the posts elements are being re rendered.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: What is `myPosts` ? An `Observable`? Of what?

Comment: it's a FirebaseListObservable

Answer (score 1):

Its a known issue in RC4. The following issue is similar.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9454